# Entity Framework DbFunctions.DiffMinutes with Int64

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework, linq, npgsql

Is there a way to force EF to use `long` as type for `DbFunctions.DiffMinutes`? Currently following code:

```
Math.Abs((long)DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(d1.Date1, d1.Date2)) > 10
```

Produces sql:

```
WHERE Abs(
    CAST (
        extract(
            epoch 
        from date_trunc(
            'minute',
            "Alias6"."Date1")
         - date_trunc(
            'minute',
            "Alias6"."Date2")
        )
    ::int4 / 60 AS int8) > 10
)
```

That fails with `ERROR:  integer out of range` error in PostgreSQL.

Is there a way to make EF to use int8 in the DateDiff?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible, since the canonical function result is fixed as `int?`

Comment: Maybe another function exists....

Comment: No AFAIK. But you could try rewriting the condition as `d1.Date1 > DbFunctions.AddMinutes(d1.Date2, 10) || d1.Date2 > DbFunctions.AddMinutes(d2.Date1, 10)` (I know it's ugly)

Comment: Are you sure it is DbFunctions.DiffMinutes that produces the out of range value? Int.MaxValue is  2,147,483,647 minutes, which is over 4000 years. What are you modelling? Age of Dinosaurs?